# Length of the URL exceeds maxUrlLength value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `MVC 5` and I have such kind of problem. With `EF6` and `ASP.net` I have some data stored in a table like this.

[image]

When I try to edit a long text like this one

**Those transactions, where 'Clock Date' is recorded, have been polled from any device or committed by PC Clock. 'Clock Date' shows the time on the device when the transaction has been performed.\nNormally 'Clock Date' should equal the 'Date' of the transaction. If not, then the transaction has been later modified by the user mentioned in the 'Applied by' column at the date and time mentioned in the 'Commit Date' column**

I am getting this error

[image]

**The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.**

I searched through `Google` and `StackOverFlow` and found some solutions, like the following, but they refer to old versions of `MVC` like `MVC` 3, 4, 4.5. I am using `MVC 5` and can't find the way to solve for my version.

MVC 3

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
```

MVC 4.0

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2000"/>
```

But I need something for `MVC 5.` Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you unfold posting data code?

Comment: Did you tried above solution? Simple `<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2000"/>`

Comment: What you mean by saying data code ?

Comment: sure, I tried that @Garath , and got this error.
**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

Comment: @RomoDaneghyan httpruntime tag is valid in web.config for every asp.net application, because it is IIS tag.

Comment: Are you using GET to push the changed text to the server? Maybe try POST instead, that doesn't put the text in the querysting.

Comment: That works,I have a longer text---Those transactions,where 'Clock Date' is recorded,have been polled from any device or committed by PC Clock.'Clock Date' shows the time on the device when the transaction has been performed.\nNormally 'Clock Date' should equal the 'Date' of the transaction. If not, then the transaction has been later modified by the user mentioned in the 'Applied by' column at the date and time mentioned in the 'Commit Date' column.--I get error which says**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**when Editing it.

Comment: Why don't you POST the data instead of GET?

Comment: in my case i had 2 `<httpRuntime ...` tag,  and i push all attributes to one of them, and remove the other.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I added the maxUrlLength attribute to my existing MVC 5 Web API 2 web.config.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxUrlLength="300" />
```